# Area of the BoundingBox matlab

Tags: matlab

```
blobAnalysis = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
'MinimumBlobArea', 100);
[areas, centroids, bbox] = step(blobAnalysis, filteredForeground);
```

Does the result in the vector areas represent the area of the blob (it measured in pixel or no)?

Comment: Yes it does. In pixels. Please format code in your question.

Comment: It's the same code, but in the vector  areas I have a values like 3000 and 400. however, the frame is 360*288.

Comment: it does make sense; a frame 360*288 means that the largest area possible is 103 680, therefore a measured area of 3000 or 400 is fine.

Comment: Thank you, what represent the four value of the vector **bbox**, the two first values coordinate of the boundingbox, and the last two values the height and width.

Comment: please see my edit and read the docs its all in there. Also if the answer helped you please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark beside it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.blobanalysis-class.html) for the `BlobAnalysis` object:

> [AREA,CENTROID,BBOX] = step(H,BW) returns the area, centroid and the
>   bounding box of the blobs when the AreaOutputPort, CentroidOutputPort
>   and BoundingBoxOutputPort properties are set to true.

Therefore, the answer to your question is YES. And the result is in pixels.

To answer your comment about the bounding box, if you read CAREFULLY the docs you will find the information:

> M-by-4 matrix of [x y width height] bounding box coordinates, where M
>   represents the number of blobs and [x y] represents the upper left
>   corner of the bounding box